# Linking errors on Qt5.11.1 in the UBUNTU 18.04

Tags: qt, qt5

I'm a little bit new in the Qt world, so maybe this question is very simple, but I do not know how to solve it.

I have installed the qt libraries using the version 5.11.1 available in this [link](http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.11/5.11.1/single/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1.tar.xz). For configuring the installation I used this command:

```
./configure -static -developer-build -opensource -confirm-license -platform linux-g++ -qt-zlib -qt-libjpeg -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-freetype -nomake examples -nomake tests -opengl desktop -qt-xcb -prefix /usr/local/Qt5.11.1
```

And after doing all the stuff for the static compilation (basically creating a kit for that) I'm getting some errors during the building step. Here they are:

```
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.a(moc_qwaylandeglwindow.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN15QtWaylandClient17QWaylandEglWindowE[_ZTVN15QtWaylandClient17QWaylandEglWindowE]+0x178): undefined reference to `QPlatformWindow::initialize()'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-egl.a(qwaylandxcompositeeglwindow.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN15QtWaylandClient27QWaylandXCompositeEGLWindowE[_ZTVN15QtWaylandClient27QWaylandXCompositeEGLWindowE]+0x168): undefined reference to `QPlatformWindow::initialize()'
/usrMakefile:1521: recipe for target 'build/release/VMTK-Neuro4.0' failed
/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-glx.a(qwaylandxcompositeglxwindow.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN15QtWaylandClient27QWaylandXCompositeGLXWindowE[_ZTVN15QtWaylandClient27QWaylandXCompositeGLXWindowE]+0x168): undefined reference to `QPlatformWindow::initialize()'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-egl-integration.a(qxcbeglwindow.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV13QXcbEglWindow[_ZTV13QXcbEglWindow]+0xd0): undefined reference to `QXcbWindow::setWindowState(QFlags<Qt::WindowState>)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-egl-integration.a(qxcbeglwindow.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV13QXcbEglWindow[_ZTV13QXcbEglWindow]+0x160): undefined reference to `QXcbWindow::startSystemMove(QPoint const&)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-egl-integration.a(qxcbeglwindow.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV13QXcbEglWindow[_ZTV13QXcbEglWindow]+0x1d8): undefined reference to `QPlatformWindow::initialize()'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-egl-integration.a(qxcbeglwindow.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV13QXcbEglWindow[_ZTV13QXcbEglWindow]+0x218): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to QXcbWindow::setWindowState(QFlags<Qt::WindowState>)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-egl-integration.a(qxcbeglwindow.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV13QXcbEglWindow[_ZTV13QXcbEglWindow]+0x2e8): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to QXcbWindow::startSystemMove(QPoint const&)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.a(qxcbglxwindow.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV13QXcbGlxWindow[_ZTV13QXcbGlxWindow]+0xd0): undefined reference to `QXcbWindow::setWindowState(QFlags<Qt::WindowState>)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.a(qxcbglxwindow.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV13QXcbGlxWindow[_ZTV13QXcbGlxWindow]+0x160): undefined reference to `QXcbWindow::startSystemMove(QPoint const&)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.a(qxcbglxwindow.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV13QXcbGlxWindow[_ZTV13QXcbGlxWindow]+0x1d8): undefined reference to `QPlatformWindow::initialize()'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.a(qxcbglxwindow.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV13QXcbGlxWindow[_ZTV13QXcbGlxWindow]+0x218): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to QXcbWindow::setWindowState(QFlags<Qt::WindowState>)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.a(qxcbglxwindow.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV13QXcbGlxWindow[_ZTV13QXcbGlxWindow]+0x2e8): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to QXcbWindow::startSystemMove(QPoint const&)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5GlxSupport.a(qglxconvenience.o): In function `qglx_surfaceFormatFromGLXFBConfig(QSurfaceFormat*, _XDisplay*, __GLXFBConfigRec*, int)':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/platformsupport/glxconvenience/qglxconvenience.cpp:308: undefined reference to `QSurfaceFormat::setColorSpace(QSurfaceFormat::ColorSpace)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5GlxSupport.a(qglxconvenience.o): In function `qglx_surfaceFormatFromVisualInfo(QSurfaceFormat*, _XDisplay*, XVisualInfo*, int)':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/platformsupport/glxconvenience/qglxconvenience.cpp:347: undefined reference to `QSurfaceFormat::setColorSpace(QSurfaceFormat::ColorSpace)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5GlxSupport.a(qglxconvenience.o): In function `qglx_reduceFormat(QSurfaceFormat*)':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/platformsupport/glxconvenience/qglxconvenience.cpp:416: undefined reference to `QSurfaceFormat::colorSpace() const'
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/platformsupport/glxconvenience/qglxconvenience.cpp:417: undefined reference to `QSurfaceFormat::setColorSpace(QSurfaceFormat::ColorSpace)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5GlxSupport.a(qglxconvenience.o): In function `qglx_buildSpec(QSurfaceFormat const&, int, int)':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/platformsupport/glxconvenience/qglxconvenience.cpp:123: undefined reference to `QSurfaceFormat::colorSpace() const'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5GlxSupport.a(qglxconvenience.o): In function `qglx_findConfig(_XDisplay*, int, QSurfaceFormat, bool, int, int)':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/platformsupport/glxconvenience/qglxconvenience.cpp:213: undefined reference to `QSurfaceFormat::colorSpace() const'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.a(qgifhandler.o): In function `QGIFFormat::decode(QImage*, unsigned char const*, int, int*, int*)':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/plugins/imageformats/gif/qgifhandler.cpp:358: undefined reference to `QImage::sizeInBytes() const'
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/plugins/imageformats/gif/qgifhandler.cpp:423: undefined reference to `QImage::sizeInBytes() const'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.a(qwebphandler.o): In function `QWebpHandler::read(QImage*)':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtimageformats/src/plugins/imageformats/webp/qwebphandler.cpp:179: undefined reference to `QImage::sizeInBytes() const'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-emu-integration.a(qeglfsemulatorintegration.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV25QEglFSEmulatorIntegration[_ZTV25QEglFSEmulatorIntegration]+0x118): undefined reference to `QEglFSDeviceIntegration::platformFunction(QByteArray const&) const'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-emu-integration.a(qeglfsemulatorintegration.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV25QEglFSEmulatorIntegration[_ZTV25QEglFSEmulatorIntegration]+0x120): undefined reference to `QEglFSDeviceIntegration::nativeResourceForIntegration(QByteArray const&)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-emu-integration.a(qeglfsemulatorintegration.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV25QEglFSEmulatorIntegration[_ZTV25QEglFSEmulatorIntegration]+0x128): undefined reference to `QEglFSDeviceIntegration::nativeResourceForScreen(QByteArray const&, QScreen*)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-kms-egldevice-integration.a(qeglfskmsegldeviceintegration.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV29QEglFSKmsEglDeviceIntegration[_ZTV29QEglFSKmsEglDeviceIntegration]+0x118): undefined reference to `QEglFSDeviceIntegration::platformFunction(QByteArray const&) const'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-kms-egldevice-integration.a(qeglfskmsegldeviceintegration.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV29QEglFSKmsEglDeviceIntegration[_ZTV29QEglFSKmsEglDeviceIntegration]+0x120): undefined reference to `QEglFSKmsIntegration::nativeResourceForIntegration(QByteArray const&)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-kms-egldevice-integration.a(qeglfskmsegldeviceintegration.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV29QEglFSKmsEglDeviceIntegration[_ZTV29QEglFSKmsEglDeviceIntegration]+0x128): undefined reference to `QEglFSKmsIntegration::nativeResourceForScreen(QByteArray const&, QScreen*)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-kms-egldevice-integration.a(qeglfskmsegldeviceintegration.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV24QEglFSKmsEglDeviceWindow[_ZTV24QEglFSKmsEglDeviceWindow]+0x30): undefined reference to `QPlatformWindow::initialize()'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-kms-egldevice-integration.a(qeglfskmsegldeviceintegration.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV24QEglFSKmsEglDeviceWindow[_ZTV24QEglFSKmsEglDeviceWindow]+0x70): undefined reference to `QPlatformWindow::setWindowState(QFlags<Qt::WindowState>)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-kms-egldevice-integration.a(qeglfskmsegldeviceintegration.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV24QEglFSKmsEglDeviceWindow[_ZTV24QEglFSKmsEglDeviceWindow]+0x140): undefined reference to `QPlatformWindow::startSystemMove(QPoint const&)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-kms-egldevice-integration.a(qeglfskmsegldevicescreen.o): In function `QEglFSKmsEglDeviceScreen::QEglFSKmsEglDeviceScreen(QKmsDevice*, QKmsOutput const&)':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_kms_egldevice/qeglfskmsegldevicescreen.cpp:51: undefined reference to `QEglFSKmsScreen::QEglFSKmsScreen(QKmsDevice*, QKmsOutput const&, bool)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-kms-egldevice-integration.a(qeglfskmsegldevicescreen.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV24QEglFSKmsEglDeviceScreen[_ZTV24QEglFSKmsEglDeviceScreen]+0xa0): undefined reference to `QEglFSKmsScreen::manufacturer() const'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-kms-egldevice-integration.a(qeglfskmsegldevicescreen.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV24QEglFSKmsEglDeviceScreen[_ZTV24QEglFSKmsEglDeviceScreen]+0xa8): undefined reference to `QEglFSKmsScreen::model() const'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-kms-egldevice-integration.a(qeglfskmsegldevicescreen.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV24QEglFSKmsEglDeviceScreen[_ZTV24QEglFSKmsEglDeviceScreen]+0xb0): undefined reference to `QEglFSKmsScreen::serialNumber() const'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-kms-egldevice-integration.a(qeglfskmsegldevicescreen.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV24QEglFSKmsEglDeviceScreen[_ZTV24QEglFSKmsEglDeviceScreen]+0xd8): undefined reference to `QEglFSKmsScreen::modes() const'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-kms-egldevice-integration.a(qeglfskmsegldevicescreen.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV24QEglFSKmsEglDeviceScreen[_ZTV24QEglFSKmsEglDeviceScreen]+0xe0): undefined reference to `QEglFSKmsScreen::currentMode() const'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-kms-egldevice-integration.a(qeglfskmsegldevicescreen.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV24QEglFSKmsEglDeviceScreen[_ZTV24QEglFSKmsEglDeviceScreen]+0xe8): undefined reference to `QEglFSKmsScreen::preferredMode() const'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-x11-integration.a(qeglfsx11integration.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV20QEglFSX11Integration[_ZTV20QEglFSX11Integration]+0x118): undefined reference to `QEglFSDeviceIntegration::platformFunction(QByteArray const&) const'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-x11-integration.a(qeglfsx11integration.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV20QEglFSX11Integration[_ZTV20QEglFSX11Integration]+0x120): undefined reference to `QEglFSDeviceIntegration::nativeResourceForIntegration(QByteArray const&)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-x11-integration.a(qeglfsx11integration.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV20QEglFSX11Integration[_ZTV20QEglFSX11Integration]+0x128): undefined reference to `QEglFSDeviceIntegration::nativeResourceForScreen(QByteArray const&, QScreen*)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5WaylandClient.a(qwaylandshmbackingstore.o): In function `QtWaylandClient::QWaylandShmBackingStore::resize(QSize const&)':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtwayland/src/client/qwaylandshmbackingstore.cpp:293: undefined reference to `QImage::sizeInBytes() const'
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtwayland/src/client/qwaylandshmbackingstore.cpp:295: undefined reference to `QImage::sizeInBytes() const'
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtwayland/src/client/qwaylandshmbackingstore.cpp:296: undefined reference to `QImage::sizeInBytes() const'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5WaylandClient.a(qwaylandshmbackingstore.o): In function `QtWaylandClient::QWaylandShmBuffer::~QWaylandShmBuffer()':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtwayland/src/client/qwaylandshmbackingstore.cpp:122: undefined reference to `QImage::sizeInBytes() const'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5WaylandClient.a(qwaylandshmbackingstore.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN15QtWaylandClient23QWaylandShmBackingStoreE[_ZTVN15QtWaylandClient23QWaylandShmBackingStoreE]+0x30): undefined reference to `QPlatformBackingStore::composeAndFlush(QWindow*, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, QPlatformTextureList*, bool)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5WaylandClient.a(qwaylandwindow.o): In function `QtWaylandClient::QWaylandWindow::setCanResize(bool)':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtwayland/src/client/qwaylandwindow.cpp:487: undefined reference to `void QWindowSystemInterface::handleGeometryChange<QWindowSystemInterface::DefaultDelivery>(QWindow*, QRect const&)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5WaylandClient.a(qwaylandwindow.o): In function `QtWaylandClient::QWaylandWindow::handleScreenChanged()':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtwayland/src/client/qwaylandwindow.cpp:929: undefined reference to `void QWindowSystemInterface::handleWindowScreenChanged<QWindowSystemInterface::DefaultDelivery>(QWindow*, QScreen*)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5WaylandClient.a(qwaylandwindow.o): In function `QtWaylandClient::QWaylandWindow::setWindowStateInternal(QFlags<Qt::WindowState>)':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtwayland/src/client/qwaylandwindow.cpp:1018: undefined reference to `void QWindowSystemInterface::handleWindowStateChanged<QWindowSystemInterface::DefaultDelivery>(QWindow*, QFlags<Qt::WindowState>, int)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5WaylandClient.a(qwaylandwindow.o): In function `QtWaylandClient::QWaylandWindow::initWindow()':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtwayland/src/client/qwaylandwindow.cpp:209: undefined reference to `QWindow::windowStates() const'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5WaylandClient.a(qwaylandwindow.o): In function `QtWaylandClient::QWaylandWindow::setGeometry(QRect const&)':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtwayland/src/client/qwaylandwindow.cpp:343: undefined reference to `void QWindowSystemInterface::handleGeometryChange<QWindowSystemInterface::DefaultDelivery>(QWindow*, QRect const&)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5WaylandClient.a(qwaylandshmwindow.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN15QtWaylandClient17QWaylandShmWindowE[_ZTVN15QtWaylandClient17QWaylandShmWindowE]+0x170): undefined reference to `QPlatformWindow::initialize()'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5WaylandClient.a(qwaylandcursor.o): In function `QtWaylandClient::QWaylandCursor::cursorBitmapImage(QCursor const*)':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtwayland/src/client/qwaylandcursor.cpp:122: undefined reference to `QImage::sizeInBytes() const'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5WaylandClient.a(qwaylandcursor.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN15QtWaylandClient14QWaylandCursorE[_ZTVN15QtWaylandClient14QWaylandCursorE]+0x80): undefined reference to `QPlatformCursor::setOverrideCursor(QCursor const&)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5WaylandClient.a(qwaylandcursor.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN15QtWaylandClient14QWaylandCursorE[_ZTVN15QtWaylandClient14QWaylandCursorE]+0x88): undefined reference to `QPlatformCursor::clearOverrideCursor()'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5WaylandClient.a(moc_qwaylandwindow_p.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN15QtWaylandClient14QWaylandWindowE[_ZTVN15QtWaylandClient14QWaylandWindowE]+0x168): undefined reference to `QPlatformWindow::initialize()'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libqtfreetype.a(ftgzip.o): In function `ft_gzip_file_init':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/freetype/src/gzip/ftgzip.c:307: undefined reference to `z_inflateInit2_'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libqtfreetype.a(ftgzip.o): In function `ft_gzip_file_done':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/freetype/src/gzip/ftgzip.c:322: undefined reference to `z_inflateEnd'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libqtfreetype.a(ftgzip.o): In function `ft_gzip_file_reset':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/freetype/src/gzip/ftgzip.c:351: undefined reference to `z_inflateReset'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libqtfreetype.a(ftgzip.o): In function `ft_gzip_file_fill_output':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/freetype/src/gzip/ftgzip.c:431: undefined reference to `z_inflate'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libqtfreetype.a(ftgzip.o): In function `FT_Gzip_Uncompress':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/freetype/src/gzip/ftgzip.c:737: undefined reference to `z_inflateInit2_'
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/freetype/src/gzip/ftgzip.c:741: undefined reference to `z_inflate'
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/freetype/src/gzip/ftgzip.c:744: undefined reference to `z_inflateEnd'
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/freetype/src/gzip/ftgzip.c:752: undefined reference to `z_inflateEnd'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5ThemeSupport.a(qgenericunixthemes.o): In function `QGnomeTheme::gtkFontName() const':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/platformsupport/themes/genericunix/qgenericunixthemes.cpp:789: undefined reference to `QString::arg(QLatin1String, int, QChar) const'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5ThemeSupport.a(qdbusplatformmenu.o): In function `QDBusPlatformMenu::QDBusPlatformMenu()':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/platformsupport/themes/genericunix/dbusmenu/qdbusplatformmenu.cpp:168: undefined reference to `QPlatformMenu::QPlatformMenu()'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5ThemeSupport.a(qdbusplatformmenu.o): In function `QDBusPlatformMenuItem::QDBusPlatformMenuItem()':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/platformsupport/themes/genericunix/dbusmenu/qdbusplatformmenu.cpp:62: undefined reference to `QPlatformMenuItem::QPlatformMenuItem()'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5ThemeSupport.a(qdbustraytypes.o): In function `iconToQXdgDBusImageVector(QIcon const&)':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/platformsupport/themes/genericunix/dbustray/qdbustraytypes.cpp:107: undefined reference to `QImage::sizeInBytes() const'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5ThemeSupport.a(moc_qdbusplatformmenu_p.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV21QDBusPlatformMenuItem[_ZTV21QDBusPlatformMenuItem]+0x70): undefined reference to `QPlatformMenuItem::setTag(unsigned long long)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5ThemeSupport.a(moc_qdbusplatformmenu_p.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV21QDBusPlatformMenuItem[_ZTV21QDBusPlatformMenuItem]+0x78): undefined reference to `QPlatformMenuItem::tag() const'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5ThemeSupport.a(moc_qdbusplatformmenu_p.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV17QDBusPlatformMenu[_ZTV17QDBusPlatformMenu]+0x90): undefined reference to `QPlatformMenu::setTag(unsigned long long)'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libQt5ThemeSupport.a(moc_qdbusplatformmenu_p.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV17QDBusPlatformMenu[_ZTV17QDBusPlatformMenu]+0x98): undefined reference to `QPlatformMenu::tag() const'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libqtlibpng.a(png.o): In function `png_compare_ICC_profile_with_sRGB':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/libpng/png.c:2368: undefined reference to `z_adler32'
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/libpng/png.c:2369: undefined reference to `z_adler32'
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/libpng/png.c:2381: undefined reference to `z_crc32'
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/libpng/png.c:2382: undefined reference to `z_crc32'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libqtlibpng.a(png.o): In function `png_reset_crc':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/libpng/png.c:130: undefined reference to `z_crc32'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libqtlibpng.a(png.o): In function `png_calculate_crc':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/libpng/png.c:173: undefined reference to `z_crc32'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libqtlibpng.a(png.o): In function `png_reset_zstream':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/libpng/png.c:986: undefined reference to `z_inflateReset'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libqtlibpng.a(pngread.o): In function `png_read_destroy':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/libpng/pngread.c:979: undefined reference to `z_inflateEnd'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libqtlibpng.a(pngrutil.o): In function `png_inflate_claim':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/libpng/pngrutil.c:407: undefined reference to `z_inflateReset2'
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/libpng/pngrutil.c:416: undefined reference to `z_inflateInit2_'
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/libpng/pngrutil.c:429: undefined reference to `z_inflateValidate'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libqtlibpng.a(pngrutil.o): In function `png_zlib_inflate':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/libpng/pngrutil.c:467: undefined reference to `z_inflate'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libqtlibpng.a(pngrutil.o): In function `png_decompress_chunk':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/libpng/pngrutil.c:662: undefined reference to `z_inflateReset'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libqtlibpng.a(pngwrite.o): In function `png_write_destroy':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/libpng/pngwrite.c:945: undefined reference to `z_deflateEnd'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libqtlibpng.a(pngwutil.o): In function `png_deflate_claim':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/libpng/pngwutil.c:395: undefined reference to `z_deflateEnd'
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/libpng/pngwutil.c:413: undefined reference to `z_deflateReset'
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/libpng/pngwutil.c:417: undefined reference to `z_deflateInit2_'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libqtlibpng.a(pngwutil.o): In function `png_text_compress':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/libpng/pngwutil.c:580: undefined reference to `z_deflate'
/usr/local/Qt5.11.3/lib/libqtlibpng.a(pngwutil.o): In function `png_compress_IDAT':
/home/everaldo/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/3rdparty/libpng/pngwutil.c:981: undefined reference to `z_deflate'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [build/release/VMTK-Neuro4.0] Error 1
16:39:32: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project VMTK-DTI_2.0 (kit: Qt 5.11.3 Static GCC (C++, x86 64bit in /usr/bin) )
When executing step "Make"
```

I looked in all the internet for a way to solve thoses linking errors, but I didn't find the libraries I'm missing. In this project I also use the glew, glm and gdcm libraries. 
So, how can I solve thoses errors? Thanks.

Comment: Your output suggests that you’re using 5.11.3, not 5.11.1 :). The linking errors are probably not missing dependencies, but libs missing from the linker line when linking statically.

Comment: Yes, you're right about the version. I'm sorry. But, do you know what libraries are missing? (I looked at some of them, for exemple the libqwayland-egl.a and they are there).

Comment: They are there, but probably not explicitly linked (like zlib). When linking statically, usually one needs to list more line explicitly, and even order matters. Probably the static build wasn't properly tested, at least not for those plugins...

Comment: But I have to include those libraries in the .pro even they are part of the Qt library?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recomemnd to use use '-prefix' with '-developer-build' options together. I can see in attached output that Qt was installed to /usr/local? Or is it used as developer-build directly from source code?

Use only one of these settings. Or you can try adjust the location of Qt installation via qt.conf (not sure if this work for developer-builds too; but works smooth for relocated qt tree)